# XSLT: how to insert tag 'mpadded' for second child of msup or msub

Tags: xslt

How to insert mpadded tag for the second child of msub|msup|msubsup elements. My coding is not working for nested child (msub|msup|msubsup) and I am getting the duplicate values also. Please suggest.

Input.xml

```
   <root>
  <disp-formula id="eqn2">
  <label>2</label>
     <math>
        <msup>
           <mrow>
              <msub>
                 <mrow><mi>E</mi></mrow>
                 <mrow><mi>T</mi></mrow>
              </msub>
           </mrow>
           <mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow>
        </msup>
     </math>
  </disp-formula>
```

XSLT:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="msub|msup|msubsup">
     <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
           <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="position() eq 3">
                 <xsl:element name="mpadded">
                    <xsl:attribute name="voffset">
                       <xsl:choose>
                          <xsl:when test="parent::*[name() eq 'msubsup']"><xsl:text>-0.16ex</xsl:text></xsl:when>
                       </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                 </xsl:element>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="position() eq 2">
                 <xsl:element name="mpadded">
                    <xsl:attribute name="voffset">
                       <xsl:choose>
                          <xsl:when test="parent::*[name() eq 'msub']"><xsl:text>0.3ex</xsl:text></xsl:when>
                          <xsl:when test="parent::*[name() eq 'msup']"><xsl:text>-0.4ex</xsl:text></xsl:when>
                          <xsl:when test="parent::*[name() eq 'msubsup']"><xsl:text>0.15ex</xsl:text></xsl:when>
                       </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                 </xsl:element>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="position() eq 1">
                 <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:otherwise>
           </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:element>
     <xsl:next-match/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required OutPut:

```
   <root>
  <disp-formula id="eqn2">
  <label>2</label>
     <math>
        <msup>
           <mrow>
              <msub>
                 <mrow><mi>E</mi></mrow>
                 <mpadded voffset="0.3ex"><mrow><mi>T</mi></mrow></mpadded>
              </msub>
           </mrow>
          <mpadded voffset="-0.4ex"><mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow></mpadded>
        </msup>
     </math>
  </disp-formula>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a template which gets applied for 2 child nodes of msub | msup | msubup

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="msub/*[count(preceding-sibling::*)=1]|msup/*[count(preceding-sibling::*)=1]|msubsup/*[count(preceding-sibling::*)=1]">
    <mpadded>
        <xsl:attribute name="voffset">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="parent::msub">0.3ex</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="parent::msup">-0.4ex</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="parent::msubsup">0.15ex</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </mpadded>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Lingamurthy, nice to see you. Now 'mpadded' tags are inserting properly, but I required attribute 'voffset' with differed values, based on some sup or subsup as their parent, see condition as given below.<xsl:when test="parent::*[name() eq 'msub']"><xsl:text>0.3ex</xsl:text></xsl:when>
                              <xsl:when test="parent::*[name() eq 'msup']"><xsl:text>-0.4ex</xsl:text></xsl:when>
                              <xsl:when test="parent::*[name() eq 'msubsup']"><xsl:text>0.15ex</xsl:text></xsl:when>

Comment: Updated the answer with the conditions for @voffset.

Comment: Thanks Lingamurthy, with help of your code, i modified as <xsl:when test="parent::*[name() eq 'msub']">, then I can able to get the desired values. Thanks a lot for your code.

Comment: test="parent::msub" should have worked too as it checks if the parent is "msub"